# finding a specific element of of a string

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have a string that looks like this:

```
string = "#$\!?/"
```

When I use the code below:

```
string.find('\')
```

I get this error

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: \ is an escape character, so try '\\'. You see it in the syntax highlighting, that the ) is part of the string

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character. So, you will have to add one more `\` to tell it's a literal character

```
In [90]: string = "#$\!?/"

In [91]: string.find('\\')
Out[91]: 2
```